# How to handle Nginx reverse proxy 502 Error in specific case?

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

Here is my nginx default

```
server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name _;

    location /login-with-args.html {
        alias /opt/code-server/login-with-args.html;
    }

}
```

And I am having login-with-args.html at this /opt/code-server/login-with-args.html location but the curl command in linux is giving me 200 but in my browser is it showing me 502 error.

this is what the url I am hitting from UI
https://url/login-with-args.html?password=1233&Id=12123&Code=sand-42&port=8127

Answer (score 0):

Generally I could have advised you to enable error logging and check the corresponding log.

But as far as I see, there are mismatches in your question. Your configuration contains `listen 80;` which, in generally, means plain HTTP, except if you're add `ssl` parameter (anyway I'd not recommend you to enable SSL/TLS on port 80). But URL you try to request is:

`https://url/login-with-args.html?password=1233&Id=12123&Code=sand-42&port=8127`

which assumes using HTTPS on port 443 (by default, if not specified other).

At the same time there is no reverse proxy defined in your configuration. You just aliased static file.

Since you got 502 error, you nginx is either located behind some proxy (or CDN) or have another server section, containing `listen` with `ssl` parameter and reverse proxy definition somewhere in configuration.